# How to create an array of numbers that range from -25 to 25 in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create a program that asks a user to input an arbitrary number of integers that are in the range of -25 to 25 inclusive and counts how many occurrences of each are entered. I also need to indicate the end of the input by entering a value outside of the range, then print the number of occurrences that were entered one or more times. I was able to do this with numbers ranging from 0 to 50, but once I entered a negative number, it gave me an Array index out of bounds error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int[] array = new int[51];
       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

      for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        
       System.out.print("Enter a number between -25 and 25: ");
       int n = s.nextInt(); 
       while (n < -25 || n > 25) 
        { 
         System.out.print("Number is out of bounds, please enter a number between -25 and 25: "); 
           n = s.nextInt(); 
         } 
          array[n]++; 
         }
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        { 
         if (array[i] > 0) 
            System.out.println("Number of " + i + "'s" + ": " + array[i]);                            
         
      }
}
```

Comment: Format your code properly so it's easier to follow. You probably want to put "continue" after the error message and the n =s.nextInt() line.

Comment: Try using maps instead of arrays. It will be much easier to count the occurrence after user input operation.

Answer (score 4):

`array` refers to an array object created with `new int[51]`.

That would be an int array with valid indices `[0]` all the way up to and including `[50]`. A negative index isn't valid; not for this array and not for any other (in java, all arrays begin at 0. Period. You can't change this).

So, what does, say, `array[-20]` mean, in your code? It looks like it means: "The value associated with user input -20", but 'user input' is not the same as 'java array index'. A negative java array index just isn't a thing (they all start at 0, after all). To java, `array[-20]` means: throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if you try this.

Presumably you want to map the input range (from `-25` all the way to `+25`) onto java's array index range (from `0` all the way to `+50` - conveniently, both ranges are exactly 51 numbers large). That should be easy enough. It's a very simple mathematical operation. Apply that in all places where relevant (whenever you use user input as an index, apply the 'map user input to array index' transformation, and whenever you have an index and need to show it to the user, apply the reverse transformation).

It's clearly homework, so I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader: What is that transformation function and how would you apply it here.

Comment: I think it's also a good suggestion to introduce with `Map` to count occurrences.

Comment: @Eklavya the way the question is set up makes it fairly clear the intent is for OP to learn about arrays. I dislike teaching a concept by asking the student to solve a problem, using the concept, but it's a problem that is better solved with some other concept - but them's the breaks.